# PHP Form not redirecting with Header- Won't redirect

Tags: php

Used this form template to create a form, and took out a few fields as they were not all necessary.

http://www.freecontactform.com/html_form.php

However, my header command is not redirecting my page. Here's the code. Please note that I have tried with and without exit at the end.

The problems isn't that it won't send out an email, but won't redirect.

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
        $email_to = "emailt@yahoo.com";

        $email_subject = "Email from email.com";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
        if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_comments .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
          $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
          if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
          $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
   }
      if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
       if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
  }
        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

       function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

header("Location: http://www.website.com/contactSoon.html");
}

?>
```

Here is the contact form I'm using-

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
                        <div class="row form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="first_name">Name *</label>
                                <input  type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                </div>
                        <div class="row form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="comments">Email Address *</label>
                                <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label for="message">Message *</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfmXB4UAAAAAHxguDJIQXClAG_8rGe6qnK1SldM"></div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting. You're almost certainly sending out headers before you call `header()`.

Comment: Your email regex is incorrect, and will fail for some valid emails. Instead use `filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`.

Comment: Try adding ob_start() at the first line of the file just next to your open PHP tag like <?php ob_start(); Also, always add exit; just on the next line to the header redirection

Comment: what shows up when you add this at the top of your code, under the opening php tag? `ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` - headers sent?

Comment: When I tried to display startup errors, I'm still getting a blank screen after I submit my form.

Comment: *"after I submit my form"* - and where is that form exactly and how are you running this as? off a webserver `http://localhost` or directly in your browser as `file:///`?

Comment: Off of a webserver. I will edit my question to add my form.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
  <?php
//memory increase max 
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

            // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
            $email_to = "emailt@yahoo.com";

            $email_subject = "Email from email.com";


        function died($error) {
            // your error code can go here
            echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
            echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
            echo $error."<br /><br />";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
            die();
        }

        // validation expected data exists
        if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
            !isset($_POST['email']) ||
            !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
            died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
        }

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
        $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

        $error_message = "";
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
            if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
            $error_comments .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
      }
              $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
              if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
              $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
       }
          if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
            $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
      }
           if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($error_message);
      }
            $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

           function clean_string($string) {
          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }

        $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    echo '<script>window.location.href = "http://www.website.com/contactSoon.html";</script>';
    //header("Location: http://www.website.com/contactSoon.html");
    }

    ?>
```

So it's going to redirect with javascript insted of php

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm still getting a blank page after I submit my form.

Comment: It's a problem with your php memory I will update the answer

Comment: Updated please make sure to test it on a server who supports php mail function email, because if you are running it locally it won't send the email ,  it will create a .txt file in a folder named mailoutput.

Comment: The problem is that it won't redirect the php file to the "thank you for contacting us" page I've created. Nor is it sending the email. I've used this code before with success, but it's not working now.

Comment: Test again with the memory limit increased

Comment: Tested again with your update, and I'm still not getting anything.

Comment: create a file with the content `<?php
phpinfo();
?>` than add this content to your question